# Observable doesn't subscribe with lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'd like to known why my lazy loaded module at which loads the test component doesn't permit that the test component subscribes to an observable injected by a test service

**index.ts**

```
export { TestComponent } from './test.component';
export { TestModule } from './test.module';
```

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from './test.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: `
        <p>{{test | async}}</p>
  `,
})
export class TestComponent {
    test: Observable<number>;
    constructor(private testService: TestService) { 
        this.test = this.testService.getObservable();
    }
}
```

**test.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';
import { TestService } from './test.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [TestComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
    ],
    providers: [TestService]
})
export class TestModule { }
```

**test.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
    getObservable(): Observable<number> {
        return from([...Array(10).keys()].reverse())
            .pipe(
                delay(1000)
            )
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, Compiler, Injector, Type, NgModuleFactory } from '@angular/core';
import { TestModule } from './test';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <ng-container #vc></ng-container>
  `,
    styles: []
})
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('vc', { read: ViewContainerRef }) containerRef: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(private compiler: Compiler, private injector: Injector) {
    }

    async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
        await this.loadComponent();
    }

    async loadComponent(): Promise<void> {
        const { TestComponent, TestModule } = await import('./test');
        const moduleFactory = await this.loadModuleFactory(TestModule);
        const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
        const factory = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TestComponent);
        this.containerRef.createComponent(factory);
    }

    private async loadModuleFactory(moduleFactory: Type<TestModule>): Promise<NgModuleFactory<TestModule>> {
        if (moduleFactory instanceof NgModuleFactory) {
            return moduleFactory;
        } else {
            return await this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(moduleFactory);
        }
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The *app.module.ts* is here only for sake of  completeness.

When all those code is compiled, the text between the *p* tag is not displayed.

Comment: Obsevables must be subscribed to, to get a value from the result. They are not asynchronous either. The are the exact same concept as a eventhandler which listens for the event. They don't care when things happen as they will wait until unsubscribed.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: @JohnPeters The async pipe is doing the subscribing here

Comment: But why subscribe in view where you can't see subscription result? Do it in code ans set debug point to validate result. If no result look at observable side.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ended up that the reason I hadn't been getting the result of my supposed observable countdown is only a rxjs thing.
I cannot understand why my approach doesn't work:

```
from([...Array(10).keys()].reverse()).pipe(delay(1000));
```

For me that would be an intuitive way of creating a countdown.
After some research on stackoverflow, I found out  some of ways of making it work correctly. Like this:

```
const timer = 10; 
interval(1000).pipe(take(timer), map(time => (timer - 1) - time));
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original example, something like this would work:

```
  numbers$: Observable<number> = from(
    Array.from(Array(10).keys()).reverse()
  ).pipe(
    concatMap(n => of(n).pipe(delay(1000))),
    tap(console.log)
  );
```

A few things:

In TypeScript, I could not use the spread operator due to this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18247

The delay operator delays the *start* of the emission, not the space in between emissions.

The concatMap will *wait* for each emission before processing the next one. By making each number an Observable and delaying it, then using the concatMap to wait, it performs the count down.

In terms of code readability, the alternate approach you suggested seems more clear:

```
  numbers$ = interval(1000).pipe(
    take(10),
    map(time => 9 - time)
  );
```